# How do I tar a directory named by my script?

Tags: linux, bash, aws-cli

I am writing a script to tar a directory, then upload the tarball to S3. The directory is named based on a date, month-year. Here is my attempt:

```
 TARNAME=`date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 months" +' %B-%Y'`

 tar cvfz /tmp/$TARNAME.tar.gz  /Drive_E/drive_i_bu/monthly/$TARNAME
 /usr/local/bin/aws s3 mv /tmp/$TARNAME.tar.gz s3://test-roger/
```

The above works, if I am not doing the variable substitution. WIth the variable, I get: `tar: July-2016.tar.gz: Cannot stattar (child): /tmp/: Cannot open: Is a directory`

Additionally, tar appears to try and dive deeper into the directory.
Any ideas?
Again, the above works without the variable substitution. So, the problem is not with the AWS CLI tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space creeping into your `$TARNAME` (see below). This causes the `/tmp/` and `July-2016.tar.gz` to be treated as separate arguments by tar

```
echo /tmp/$TARNAME.tar.gz
/tmp/ July-2016.tar.gz
```

If you get rid of that, things should work as you expect. It appears to be caused by the space in

```
' %B-%Y'
```

Answer (score -3):

Mind the white spaces:

`tar cvfz /tmp/"${TARNAME}".tar.gz  /Drive_E/drive_i_bu/monthly/"${TARNAME}"
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 mv /tmp/"${TARNAME}.tar.gz" s3://test-roger/`

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the older and accepted answer.

Comment: @HBruijn I disagree. This answer does add **something** which is not in the accepted answer. This answer shows how to quote a variable name in a way that will work with spaces. The accepted answer doesn't do that.

Comment: Well, I think sometimes quoting variables with spaces is the solution. Not always You can remove the spaces.